# How to use the Google Translate API in React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-translate

I've looked at the docs and many other websites, but nothing I've tried has worked. There must be a way to use google translate in a react native app, but I'm stuck. How can I implement google translate into my react native app? My app needs to be able to translate words and phrases.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for React-native.
See
https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api/issues/98

Answer (score -1):

One of the best solutions I found is [Google-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api). I think it can do everything you need in a very simple way

Comment: This didn't work when I tried it, and I've tried multiple times and so has my partner. :( I'm pretty sure we followed all the steps correctly. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Have you first used it to test, as given in their usage?

Comment: I copied their code from usage, but it kept throwing an error from safe-eval which is one of the api's dependencies. I didn't understand how to fix this. I tried updating safe-eval to the latest version but this didn't fix the error.

Comment: can you add an example for a react-native project?

Comment: Any option to translate the language from one to another in react-native?