# How to use Google translate in react native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am quite new to react native, and I'm working on an app that does translation with dynamic text.

For the past week, I tried to use the google api in my app, but couldn't find a solution that works with react native. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525388/how-to-use-the-google-translate-api-in-react-native-app), for example, didn't help me since the package is deprecated.
The only solutions that I found were apparently working with Node.js (which I have no idea how to use it in my app).

So I wanted to ask what is the easiest way to use google translate in my react native app?